# SCSSPHP SASS importng issues

Tags: php, sass

Trying to get into working with SASS. As a PHP developer I have decided to work with leafo/scssphp.

At the moment I have gotten thing working to load a specific scss file.

I have created a page called styles.php with the code below.

```
require "../scssphp/scss.inc.php";

use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler;
use Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Expanded;

$formatterName = "Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Expanded";
$scss = new Compiler();
$scss->setFormatter($formatterName);

$server = new scss_server("../stylesheets", null, $scss);
$server->serve();
```

I access the page with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.php/custom.scss">
```

The above works however if I add an @import 'buttons' in my custom.scss file, for example, then the page simple compiles with the words @import 'buttons' rather than importing the partial file.

If I update my code to:

```
require "../scssphp/scss.inc.php";

use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler;
use Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Expanded;

$formatterName = "Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Expanded";
$scss = new Compiler();
$scss->setImportPaths('../assets/stylesheets/');
$scss->setFormatter($formatterName);
echo $scss->compile('@import "custom";');
```

Then the file imports all the partials but the styles don't actually get applied.

The main question is how to import a specific .scss file and all its partials correctly so that the styles load on the page.

Comment: OK so I ended up adding the css header to my php file.

`header('Content-Type: text/css');`

This works except for some reason I can't seem to import mixins and have them work?